# Apps script permissions issue

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, authorization, sidebar

I created a spreadsheet for use of multiple people with editor access. I created a button that each person can press to display a sidebar with instructions on how to use the spreadsheet. Simple html. I granted permission the first time I ran the code for the sidebar.

Question?  Every person that tries to access the button to display the sidebar has to grant permission the first time. How do I prevent this from happening?  I am not the owner of the spreadsheet but I have editor access to the sheet.

I granted permission to the script. Does the spreadsheet owner have to grant permission to the script to prevent everyone else from having to grant permission?

Answer (score 0):

In order to prevent others from having to grant permission to the script, the owner of the spreadsheet will need to grant permission to the script. As an editor, you can request that the owner do this by going to the "Script editor" in the spreadsheet and clicking on the "Share" button in the top right corner. This will bring up a dialog where you can enter the email address of the owner and request that they grant permission to the script.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, every person that tries to execute a script, in this case by clicking a button to open to diplay the sidebar, should authorize the script before the script is able to open the sidebar.

There is no way to prevent this to happen, but you might avoid this to  happen on every spreadsheet by creating and add-on instead of using a bounded script to each spreadsheet.